# Advanced Custom Fields: multiple checkbox values displaying conditional data

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, conditional-statements, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using Advanced Custom Fields with Wordpress and I’m using the checkbox field to display data depending on what is selected. The return value of the field is set to 'Value'.

I have two checkboxes and I’m getting data based on whether one or the other is selected. But is it possible to show data when both checkboxes are selected?

For example:

```
<?php $options = get_field('options');?>
<?php if( $options && in_array('option-1', $options) ): ?>
  <p>Option 1 selected</p>
<?php elseif ( $options && in_array('option-2', $options) ): ?>
  <p>Option 2 selected</p>
<?php elseif ( $options && in_array('option-1', $options) && in_array('option-2', $options ): ?>
  <p>Option 1 and Option 2 selected</p>
<?php endif;?>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes its possible using `in_array_all` in your last `elseif` for checking both checkbox selected.

```
     <?php $options = get_field('options');
     $options = array($options); ?>
<?php if( $options && in_array(array('option-1','option-2'), $options)): ?>
     <p>Option 1 and Option 2 selected</p>
<?php elseif ( $options && in_array(array('option-2'), $options) ): ?>
  <p>Option 2 selected</p>
<?php elseif ($options && in_array(array('option-1'), $options) ): ?> 
 <p>Option 1 selected</p>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: Hey - thanks for this. However, this is causing an error - I'm just getting a blank page now so I guess the code isn't quite right.

Comment: please could you please let me know what is the error?

Comment: I'm getting 'Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in /xxxx'

Comment: I have edited my answer now so please copy that whole answer and use it.

Comment: That's almost got it. I'm now getting the data for when both are selected, but no data for the single options now :)

Comment: please check again i updated the code.just copy above code i have tested with all scenarios

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174262/discussion-between-raju-eww-and-abbas-arezoo).