# Advanced Custom Fields: ticking checkboxes to display specific content

Tags: arrays, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

With reference to this post:
[Advanced Custom Fields: multiple checkbox values displaying conditional data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51152997/advanced-custom-fields-multiple-checkbox-values-displaying-conditional-data)

I am trying to state within the code (below) that if one box is checked, an image with link will be displayed. If two boxes checked, two images with their links will be displayed.

```
<?php 
   $fittings = get_field('fittings'); 
?>
<?php 
   if(in_array('ledPanel', get_field('fittings'), TRUE ) ) 
   {
       echo '<li><a href="/products/led-panel-light/"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/s_subcategories12aC.png" alt="LED Panel" /></a></li>';
   } 
   elseif(in_array('ledBatten', get_field('fittings'), TRUE ) ) 
   {
       echo '<li><a href="/products/litelite-led-batten/"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/s_subcategories50aC.png" alt="LED Batten" /></a></li>';
   } 
   elseif(in_array('ledHighbay', get_field('fittings'), TRUE ) ) 
   {
       echo '<li><a href="/products/led-highbay/"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/s_subcategories141aA.png" alt="LED Highbay" /></a></li>';
   } 
   elseif(in_array('ledPanel', get_field('fittings'), TRUE ) && in_array('ledBatten', get_field('fittings'), TRUE)){
     echo '<li><a href="/products/led-highbay/"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/s_subcategories141aA.png" alt="LED Highbay" /></a></li>
      <li><a href="/products/led-highbay/"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/s_subcategories141aA.png" alt="LED Highbay" /></a></li>';
} ?>
```

Can someone suggest what I am doing wrong here please? Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

```
<?php $fittings = get_field('fittings'); ?>

<?php if(in_array('ledPanel', get_field('fittings'), TRUE ) ) {
echo '<li><a href="/products/led-panel-light/"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/s_subcategories12aC.png" alt="LED Panel" /></a></li>';
} if(in_array('ledBatten', get_field('fittings'), TRUE ) ) {
echo '<li><a href="/products/litelite-led-batten/"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/s_subcategories50aC.png" alt="LED Batten" /></a></li>';
} if(in_array('ledHighbay', get_field('fittings'), TRUE ) ) {
echo '<li><a href="/products/led-highbay/"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/s_subcategories141aA.png" alt="LED Highbay" /></a></li>';
} ?>
```